# Segmentation fault when using boost::numpy::ndarray

Tags: python, c++, boost, numpy

I am getting what I think is a strange seg fault when I am trying to pass `boost::numpy::ndarray` as an argument:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/numpy.hpp>


void say_hello(boost::numpy::ndarray& my_array)
//void say_hello(int x) This works fine
{
  std::cout<<"Hello"<<std::endl;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("say_hello", say_hello);

}
```

I know the example is silly, but I should not be getting a seg fault there, and this is the smallest example I was able to reduce the problem to. Maybe I need to specify the `ndarray` type or number of dimensions, but I could not find any documentation on it. I was looking at [this](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/boost_numpy/html/namespaceboost_1_1numpy.html), but it didn't seem very helpful. My gut feeling is I am missing something simple, but I just don't see it.

When I run this:

```
In [1]: from hello_ext import *

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: say_hello(np.array([3,4,5]))
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

My Makefile:

```
PYTHON_VERSION = 2.7
PYTHON_INCLUDE = /usr/include/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)


BOOST_INC = /usr/include
BOOST_LIB = /usr/lib

TARGET = hello_ext

$(TARGET).so: $(TARGET).o
    g++ -std=c++11 -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic $(TARGET).o -L$(BOOST_LIB) -lboost_python -lboost_numpy -L/usr/lib/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)/config -lpython$(PYTHON_VERSION) -o $(TARGET).so

$(TARGET).o: $(TARGET).cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -I$(PYTHON_INCLUDE) -I$(BOOST_INC) -fPIC -c $(TARGET).cp
```

Answer (score 11):

I knew it was something simple. I needed to add these two lines:

```
Py_Initialize();
boost::numpy::initialize();
```

as explained : [here](https://github.com/ndarray/Boost.NumPy/blob/master/libs/numpy/doc/tutorial/simple.rst) seg fault results after any attempt to use `boost::numpy::ndarray` if the above lines are not ran.

Therefore: my file becomes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/numpy.hpp>


void say_hello(boost::numpy::ndarray& my_array)
//void say_hello(int x) This works fine
{
  std::cout<<"Hello"<<std::endl;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    Py_Initialize();
    boost::numpy::initialize();
    def("say_hello", say_hello);
}
```

Comment: But in the linked example, the initialisation is done in a C++ `main()`. Here, we are in a python module.

Comment: Thank you very much!! This is the kind of cryptic segfault not even GDB can help with