# Wrap C++ function with Boost Python -- numpy array types

Tags: python, c++, macos, numpy, boost

From what I gather, a good way to do this is to use the [Boot.Python](https://github.com/boostorg/python/tree/master) library, like [this simple example](https://github.com/boostorg/python/blob/master/example/numpy/simple.cpp); please don't recommend alternatives like Cython as a solution. But when I try to use `boost::python` data types, my cpp file won't build.

example_boost.cpp:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>

#include <iostream>

namespace bpy = boost::python;
namespace bnp = boost::python::numpy;

void do_stuff(const bnp::ndarray& input_array) {
    ...
};

/*
 * This is a macro Boost.Python provides to signify a Python extension module. This enables me to import example_boost.cpp and call do_stuff() within a Python file. 
 */
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(crf) {
    // Expose the functions
    boost::python::def("compute_factor_out_msgs", compute_factor_out_msgs);
}
```

Running `make`...

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "boost::python::converter::object_manager_traits<boost::python::numpy::ndarray>::get_pytype()", referenced from:
          boost::python::detail::caller_arity<1u>::impl<OutMessages (*)(boost::python::numpy::ndarray const&), boost::python::default_call_policies, boost::mpl::vector2<OutMessages, boost::python::numpy::ndarray const&> >::operator()(_object*, _object*) in example_boost.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make: *** [example_boost.so] Error 1
```

Notes:

- `make` was successful if I don't use the `bpy` and `bnp` types, so my Makefile is correct.
- I have Boost v 1.63.0 installed via homebrew, on Mac OSX El Capitan
- Using C++ 11 and Python 2.7

Comment: *`make` was successful if I don't use the `bpy` and `bnp` types, so my Makefile is correct.* Nope, it misses the linker flags to the libraries providing the symbols in `bpy` and `bnp`.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems with the posted example code:

1. To resolve the make issue, the Makefile would have to also link `-lboost_numpy`.
2. Even though it would compile, the result would be a seg fault (stack overflow) because we need to first initialize with

   Py_Initialize();
   bnp::initialize();

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719262/segmentation-fault-when-using-boostnumpyndarray).